# Re-running "page.razor.js"'s global lines when the user revists the razor page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I created an ASP.NET 6.0 Blazor Server-side project. I added "Index.razor.js", and loaded it in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` of the "Index.razor" page like below.

```
<div id="output" style="height:40px; width:100px; border-style: solid;"></div>

@code {
    IJSObjectReference js;
    System.Timers.Timer updateTimer;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        js = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/Index.razor.js");
    ....
```

At the start of the "Index.razor.js", I got the DIV like below.

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");

export function update() {
    ....updates the text of output...
```

This works when I first visit the index page. But if I click another page like Counter and then come back to the index page, calling the `update()` method does not update the `output` DIV. It seems as if the `var output` is holding a different DIV than the current `output` DIV. My guess is that it may be holding the `output` DIV of the previously opened index page, and the current index page has a different `output` DIV.

Why is this so? I imported the JS file in `OnAfterRenderAsync`, so shouldn't the `var output = document.getElementById("output");` be executed again when the user revisits the index page? If not, how can I re-execute the `var output = document.getElementById("output");` line when the user re-visits the index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the element `id` attribute. Instead use `ElementReference` and pass the value to JavaScript.

#### Blazor Component:

```
<div @ref="MyElementReference" />

@code {
    private ElementReference MyElementReference{ get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyJsFunction", MyElementReference);
    }
}
```

I also recommend adding your JavaScript to `index.html` on `WASM` or `_Layout.cshtml` on `Server Side`.

#### Using ElementReference in JavaScript:

```
window.MyBlazor = {
    MyJsFunction: function (element) {
        element.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum...";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is server-side, so there is no index.html, but _layout or _host. But aren't those files used for all razor pages? If I only need the script for only one razor page, isn't it bad to add the script to _layout/_host that apply to all razor pages?

Comment: @DamnVegetables, I've not used the collocated JavaScript files yet, never seen a reason for it. Just looked it up, and looks like you can add it to the component itself like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component . In retrospect, this could prove useful.